# How to use JOIN in UPDATE mysql query

Tags: mysql, pdo

Hello I want to bind this to one query with JOIN.
How does this work:

```
Db::bind("uid", strip_tags($userid));
DB::bind("user_id", strip_tags($refer));
Db::bind("points_earn", strip_tags($points_earn));
Db::bind("points_refer", strip_tags($points_refer));
Db::query("UPDATE referrals SET `points_earn` = :points_earn WHERE new_id = :uid");
Db::query("UPDATE users SET `points` = `points` + :points_refer WHERE id = :user_id");
```

What I think but not work.

```
Db::query("UPDATE referrals r JOIN users u ON r.user_id = u.id SET `r.points_earn` = :points_earn WHERE r.new_id = :uid AND `u.points` = `u.points` + :points_refer WHERE u.id = :user_id");
```

Have anyone a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is right, but the back ticks are wrong and each `SELECT` only has one `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE referrals r JOIN
       users u
       ON r.user_id = u.id
   SET r.points_earn = :points_earn
   WHERE r.new_id = :uid AND u.points = u.points + :points_refer AND
         u.id = :user_id;
```

The problem with backticks is that the following are quite different:

```
`r.points_earn`
`r`.`points_earn`
```

The first refers to a column called "r.points_earn".  The second refers to the "points_earn" column in "r".  The backticks aren't necessary so you can just remove them.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer and they knows that with " u.points = u.points + :points_refer AND
         u.id = :user_id;" u.id = :user_id is meaning as WHERE ? because the had to change the points where u.id = :user_id